# jQuery Datatables specificity

Tags: jquery, datatables, css-specificity

I want to hover over an icon in a [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) row within a Bootstrap 4 grid. 
I know about CSS specificity but cannot get to my table row. I wish that Google developer tools had a way to calculate specificity.

### This works in CSS

```
body .table.dataTable tbody td { 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Why don't any of these work in the selector?

```
$( "body .table.dataTable tbody td" ).hover(function() {
    alert('test');
});

$( "#mytable" ).hover(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: are those event in a $(document).ready scope ? 
Can you try changing to : $(document).on("hover", "#mytable", function() { alert('test'); }); ?

Comment: Yes. They're in `$(function() { });` I'll give your suggestion a try. Thanks.

Comment: if it does not work please include your html and create a jsfiddle so we can help you easier

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me.  `$('#tableSales').on('mouseover', 'td', function () {
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ });
});`

Comment: This is not an issue of specificity. The concept of specificity doesn't exist outside of CSS.